# chrome creating extra space beneath div

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, positioning

I am having a bug where chrome inserts the smallest amount of extra space beneath an iframe.  See here http://jsfiddle.net/hrp27/ .  The entirety of the code is

```
<div class="subwindow" style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <div id="blog" style="line-height: 0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid main-holder">
            <iframe src="http://elju.github.io" frameborder="0">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This same issue does not happen in firefox.  I have looked at it for a while and can't tell what's causing the problem.  I'm asking because I'm having a similar problem on my website at http://secure-shore-8758.herokuapp.com/.  Chrome seems to be, for some reason, auto inserting an overflow-y: auto into my code without me telling it to.  If anybody can explain this behavior, that'd be great!

Comment: Can you also post your related css code?

Comment: This is actually all the code it takes to do it.  If you open up that fiddle in chrome, it has scroll bars on the far right, but the same doesn't happen in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You have a property "line-height: 0px" on your "blog" element. remove it to fix the extra space

Or you can change the overflow-y property of the subwindow class to "none" like this:

```
 <div class="subwindow" style="overflow-y: none;">
    <div id="blog" style="line-height: 0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid main-holder">
            <iframe src="http://elju.github.io" frameborder="0">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But do you have any idea why this is happening in chrome but not firefox? And also, I'm confusing why specifying the line-height is 0px makes the div change positions. Chrome developer toolkit is telling me that both .blog and .subwindow are the same height in pixels, so I am really confused what's causing the scrollbars to occur.